# Angular subscribe loop in subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework, subscribe

I am looking to retrieve documents for each city.

I have a first http GET retrieving cities by parsing the page and then I need to make an other request for each city to retrieve associated documents.

**What I have done**

```js
this.httpService.callUrl(ifrUrl).subscribe((html: string) => {
const root = parse(html);
const nodes = root.querySelectorAll(IFR_AIRPORTS_SELECTOR);
const airports = [];
for (const node of nodes) { // Loop for each city
  if (node.childNodes.length === 2) {
    const linkElement = node.childNodes[1];
    // @ts-ignore
    const link = linkElement.attributes.href;
    const airportUrl = this.urlService.getIfrUrlWithEnd(link);
    const airportName = linkElement.innerText.trim().replace('\n', ' ');
    // @ts-ignore
    const icaoSplit = linkElement.attributes.id.toString().split('.');
    const icao = icaoSplit[icaoSplit.length - 1];
    // Retrieve documents associated to the actual airport
    // with an other http request
    this.getIfrChartsForUrl(airportUrl).subscribe((charts) => {
      const airport = new IfrAirport();
      airport.icao = icao;
      airport.name = airportName;
      airport.url = airportUrl;
      airport.charts = charts;
    });
  }
}
console.log('Airports');
console.log(airports);
```

I am not really familiar with asynchrone functions. Here I try afterward to display the airport but the log is display directly after running the script with empty airport array...

The array build `airports` should be returned.

What am I missing?

T H A N K S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of nested subscriptions and subscriptions in a loop you could use RxJS higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map an observable and `forkJoin` function to combine multiple observables.

Try the following

```js
this.httpService.callUrl(ifrUrl).pipe(
  switchMap((html: string) => {
    const root = parse(html);
    const nodes = root.querySelectorAll(IFR_AIRPORTS_SELECTOR);
    const requests = [];
    for (const node of nodes) { // Loop for each city
      if (node.childNodes.length === 2) {
        const linkElement = node.childNodes[1];
        // @ts-ignore
        const link = linkElement.attributes.href;
        const airportUrl = this.urlService.getIfrUrlWithEnd(link);
        const airportName = linkElement.innerText.trim().replace('\n', ' ');
        // @ts-ignore
        const icaoSplit = linkElement.attributes.id.toString().split('.');
        const icao = icaoSplit[icaoSplit.length - 1];

        requests.push(
          this.getIfrChartsForUrl(airportUrl).pipe(
            map(charts => {
              const airport = new IfrAirport();
              airport.icao = icao;
              airport.name = airportName;
              airport.url = airportUrl;
              airport.charts = charts;

              return airport;
            })
          )
        );
      }
    }

    return forkJoin(requests);
  })
).subscribe(
  airports => console.log(airports),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```